# Error al insertar pdf con fecha en un formulario php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando almacenar en una base de datos archivos PDF a través de un formulario en PHP.
Código HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        <label for="nombreBoletin" class="control-label">Nombre Boletín</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombreBoletin" id="nombreBoletin"><br>
        <label for="archivoPDF" class="control-label">Archivo PDF</label>
        <input type="file" name="archivoPDF" id="archivoPDF"><br>
        <label for="provincia" class="control-label">Provincia</label>
        <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia"><br>
        <label for="fechaBoletin" class="control-label">Fecha Boletín</label>
        <input type="date" name="fechaBoletin" id="fechaBoletin" value="yyyy/mm/dd"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar" id="enviar">
    </form>
```

Código PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $nombreBoletin = $_POST['nombreBoletin'];
    $archivoPDF = $_FILES['archivoPDF']['name'];
    $archivoPDF_type = $_FILES['archivoPDF']['type'];
    $archivoPDF_data = file_get_contents($_FILES['archivoPDF']['tmp_name']); 
    $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
    $fechaBoletin = $_POST['fechaBoletin'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO boletines values (null,'$nombreBoletin','$archivoPDF_data','$provincia',date_format('$fechaBoletin', '%d-%m-%Y'))";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if ($consulta){
        echo "La inserción se ha realizado con éxito.";
    }else{
        echo "Error en la inserción de los datos.";
    }
}
```

La tabla a la que intento subir el pdf es:

```
create table boletines(
    id int(4) auto_increment,
    nombre varchar(255) not null,
    pdf mediumblob not null,
    provincia_comunidad_autonoma varchar(255) not null,
    fecha_boletin date not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Creo que el problema es en la fecha, pero tampoco descarto que sea del pdf... La configuración del php.ini ya la he tocado y está todo bien.

Gracias.

Comment: Deberías usar una sentencia preparada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo al manual de MySQL para columnas [tipo `DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays **DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format**. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Básicamente, los valores son almacenados en el formato `YYYY-MM-DD` y cualquier otro formato va a generar error. Mientras que la función [date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) es usada para formatear fechas al leer, no al guardar.

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $nombreBoletin = $_POST['nombreBoletin'];
    $archivoPDF = $_FILES['archivoPDF']['name'];
    $archivoPDF_type = $_FILES['archivoPDF']['type'];
    $archivoPDF_data = file_get_contents($_FILES['archivoPDF']['tmp_name']); 
    $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];
    // La fecha debe estar en el formato adecuado: YYYY-MM-DD
    $fechaBoletin = $_POST['fechaBoletin'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO boletines values (null, '$nombreBoletin', '$archivoPDF_data', '$provincia', '$fechaBoletin')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if ($consulta){
        echo "La inserción se ha realizado con éxito.";
    }else{
        echo "Error en la inserción de los datos.";
    }
}
```

Otra cosa a verificar es el tamaño de los archivos. Por defecto, PHP restringe el tamaño de archivos a subir y la cantidad de datos provenientes de un formulario procesado con método POST y, de ser necesario, deberás modificar estas variables en `php.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize = 3M
post_max_size = 3M
```

Asegúrate de colocar un valor adecuado, guardar el archivo y reiniciar Apache para aplicar los cambios.

En caso de que los archivos a guardar en la base de datos sean muy grandes, deberás revisar la configuración de MySQL para [permitir paquetes grandes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html) o, en su defecto, usar
consultas preparadas, dividir el archivo y agregarlo a la consulta con [send_long_data()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php#example-1472)

### Recomendación:

Definitivamente debes migrar a [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para evitar errores por no escapar los valores y, de paso, minimizar el riesgo de ataques SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Si el tamaño del pdf es mayor a 1Mb**, puedes tener problemas en dos puntos:

1. Carga del archivo. Verifica si hubo error en la carga

```
    $errores = array( UPLOAD_ERR_OK => 'Carga exitosa'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => 'Excede el tamaño de carga (PHP)'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => 'Excede el tamaño de carga (HTML)'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => 'Carga incompleta'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => 'No se seleccionó archivo'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => 'Falta carpeta temporal'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => 'No se guardó el archivo'
                    , UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => 'Una extensión bloqueó la carga'
                    );
    if( $_FILES['archivoPDF']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
       echo $errores[$_FILES['archivoPDF']['error']]
    }
```

2. Envío a la base de datos. Dependiendo de la configuración de la conexión y el servidor podría ser necesario enviar el archivo "en pedazos".

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO boletines(nombre, pdf, provincia_comunidad_autonoma, fecha_boletin)
                               VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? )
                            "
                          );
    $blob = null; // Las sentencias preparadas necesitan una referencia
    $fecha = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['fechaBoletin']) );
    $stmt->bind_param( 'sbss'
                     , $_POST['nombreBoletin'] 
                     , $blob
                     , $_POST['provincia']
                     , $fecha
                     );
    $stmt->send_long_data( 1, file_get_contents($_FILES['archivoPDF']['tmp_name']) );
    
    if( $consulta = $stmt->execute() ){
        echo 'La inserción se ha realizado con éxito.';
    }else{
        echo 'Error en la inserción de los datos. '.$stmt->error;
        // ER_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE ?
    }
}
```

Dependiendo del problema será la solución, considerando varios factores. El código propuesto es una base para diagnóstico.

** A partir de 1Mb, considerando valores predeterminados típicos.

Comment: Sin "partir" el contenido y al no estar dentro de un ciclo, con `send_log_data()` envías el archivo completo en un solo paso; creo que es lo mismo que enlazar el parámetro directamente. Supongo que se debería analizar el valor de `max_allowed_packet`. En el [ejemplo del manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php#example-1472) se agregan 8kb en cada iteración, combinado con las funciones de apertura, lectura y cierre de archivo.

Comment: @Triby: Es cierto, realmente la intención de ponerlo así cachar si ocurre un `ER_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE` y a partir de ahí, como bien dices, averiguar y decidir ya sea cambiando la configuración del cliente y/o del servidor o dividir el archivo como mencionas. ¿Es lo mismo que enlazar el parámetro directamente? no necesariamente, ya que eliminas el overhead del resto de la sentencia.

Comment: ¿Realmente se elimina el "overhead" o solo se cambia de enlazar a enviar paquete grande?

Comment: Para quitar el entrecomillado, usemos exceso o [sobrecosto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobrecoste_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Comunicaciones_(sobrecoste_de_la_transferencia_de_datos)). La [operación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.html) ocurre a nivel de protocolo.

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia e insistencia, en el enlace que proporcionas acerca del sobrecosto se menciona _"... precisa de enviar más información que la propia carga útil."_, y `send_long_data()` parece implicar un sobrecosto. Por otra parte, en el enlace de MySQL no se mencionan ventajas entre enlazar parámetros o enviar paquetes grandes, excepto por la posibilidad de **enviarlos por partes** cuando se excede el tamaño permitido y, en mi precario entender, es donde se puede justificar el sobrecosto, _"para establecer una transmisión fiable de la información en cuestión."_

Comment: Si consideras el BLOB como la carga útil, el sobrecosto son las otras columnas; por eso los ingenieros de MySQL incluyeron a un nivel mas bajo -a nivel de [protocolo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-stmt-send-long-data.html)- el envío exclusivo de una columna, ya sea en uno o varios paquetes; precisamente, sin enlazarlo en la llamada en la que va la sentencia junto con el valor del resto de las columnas.